# Does the application of a new layer of lacquer dissolve pinhole bubbles?

Tags: repair, hardwood

I am brushing on lacquering to 50 small walnut plates.   My first coats were a bit of a learning curve and I had produced some small bubbles.  My understanding is that new coats of lacquer will dissolve into the previous coats fixing small imperfections.  After my 2nd coat of Watco's clear finish dried for 2 hours (as label recommended), I applied my 3rd and anticipated final coat.  No new bubbles, but the previous ones are still present.  Isn't lacquer re-coats supposed to dissolve/remove pinhole bubbles?

Should I.....
    1. Sand with 400 grit and apply another coat
    2. Rub out and see if its enough
    3. Apply a bit of lacquer thinner +/- lacquer and re-coat.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, a further coat does not dissolve dried bubbles in a varnish coat.

You will need to sand it back and recoat, but 400 grit? I would suggest much finer.